# Wait for WCF async method to complete before continue

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, win-universal-app

I've been trying for hours to wait for an async method to complete before continue with the application. If I debug everything works great because I'm actually waiting for the async method to complete but without debugging the code executes while calling the method and nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
private async void MenuPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItems = await SetItemSource();
            ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>>((AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>.CreateGroups(MenuItems, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, s => s.MenuName, true)));
            ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["MenuGroups"]).Source = ItemSource;
        }

        private async Task<ObservableCollection<Menu>> SetItemSource()
        {
            return await MyWinService.GetMenuEntriesAsync();

        }
```

Comment: I did this but still fails:

Comment: private Task<ObservableCollection<Menu>> SetItemSource()
        {
            return MyWinService.GetMenuEntriesAsync();
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

Remove the async/await in the SetItemSource method. You are returning an awaitable task that is telling MenuPage_Loaded to continue at that point.
Async is not required in the second method as there is no continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did this:

```
private async void MenuPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var MenuItemsTask = MyWinService.GetMenuEntriesAsync();
            MenuItems = await MenuItemsTask;
            ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>>((AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>.CreateGroups(MenuItems, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, s => s.MenuName, true)));
            ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["MenuGroups"]).Source = ItemSource;
        }
```

I swear it was not working but I republished my ServiceReference (without changing anything) and suddenly it works, I mean, I don't know what is happening, I hate to not know what happened haha.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nevermind, it started working and now it is failing again.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what is happening, sometimes I get a "Your service has been hosted message next to the clock" when that happens everything works but sometimes it is not hosted, why?